# Dealing with daylight savings time - C++

Tags: c++, time, timezone, dst, ctime

Given an input date and time (in string format), I am trying to get the epoch time for it using `time` functions given in `ctime` like `mktime`. Converting the `time_t` epoch time back to a date and time results in a date and time that is one hour less than the original. I have gone through some discussions which say that there may be an adjustment of one hour in case of daylight savings time. Here is the code:

```
//sample strptime program.

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

long parseTime(string time) {

  cout << "Time entered = " << time << endl;

  long timeSinceEpoch;

  struct tm t;

  if(time.find("/") != string::npos) {
    //format of date is mm/dd/yyyy. followed by clock in hh:mm (24 hour clock).
    if(strptime(time.c_str(), "%m/%e/%Y %H:%M", &t) == NULL) {
      cout << "Error. Check string for formatting." << endl;
    }
  } else if(time.find("-") != string::npos) {
    //format of date is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (hh in 24 hour clock format).
    cout << "I am here." << endl;
    if(strptime(time.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%e %H:%M:%S", &t) == NULL) {
      cout << "Error. Check string for formatting of new date." << endl;
    }
  }

  cout << "Details of the time structure:" << endl;
  cout << "Years since 1900 = " << t.tm_year << endl;
  cout << "Months since January = " << t.tm_mon << endl;
  cout << "Day of the month = " << t.tm_mday << endl;
  cout << "Hour = " << t.tm_hour << " Minute = " << t.tm_min << " second = " << t.tm_sec << endl;

  timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
  time_t temp = mktime(&t);
  cout << "Time since epoch = " << timeSinceEpoch << endl;

  cout << "Reconverting to the time structure:" << endl;
  struct tm* t2 = localtime(&temp);
  cout << "Details of the time structure:" << endl;
  cout << "Years since 1900 = " << t2->tm_year << endl;
  cout << "Months since January = " << t2->tm_mon << endl;
  cout << "Day of the month = " << t2->tm_mday << endl;
  cout << "Hour = " << t2->tm_hour << " Minute = " << t2->tm_min << " second = " << t2->tm_sec << endl;

  return timeSinceEpoch;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  string date, t;
  cout << "Enter date: " << endl;
  cin >> date;
  cout << "Enter time: " << endl;
  cin >> t;

  struct tm time;
  string overall = date + " " + t;

  long result = parseTime(overall);
  cout << "Time in date + time = " << overall << " and since epoch = " << result << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The troublesome input is:
date: 2013-03-11
time: 04:41:53

My questions(s):
1. Checking for `tm_idst` flag returns a non-zero, indicating that DST is in effect. However, how do I know what timezone is being talked about?
2. The timestamp given above may not have been recorded in the same time zone as I am in. Is there a way to specify timezone so that the `tm_idst` flags are correctly set?
3. How do I deal with DST when I am unsure of what timezone the timestamp was recorded in?

Comment: Getting the timezone depends on your operating system and C library, there are no standard or platform independent way to get it. On Linux with glibc, for example, there is an extra member field in the `tm` structure called `tm_zone`, which is a C-style string containing the timezone abbreviation.

Comment: @Joachim: I tried the `tm_zone` option, but it seems it is not there. So basically, I just get time since epoch, re-convert to `struct tm` and if there is an hour's difference, add 3600 seconds to it? Is that the only option I have of dealing with DST?

Comment: a comment - if you're accepting 'kind of' ISO dates, then the correct input format is YYYY-MM-DD (i.e. 4 + 2 + 2 **always***) - so the parse for this is `%Y-%m-%d`, the %e format in theory accepts a leading space for single digit dates, while [ISO always expects two digits for the month and year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I would recommend boost, or another toolkit for helping with this, mind you it's always possible to use the [raw tzdata and tzcode](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) and write classes around it

Comment: @Petesh: I used `%e` after reading the documentation here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00%2Fstrptip.htm. It seems we can use either `%d` or `%e` (both have the exact same description).

Answer (score 2):

Plain `C++` is pretty sparse with timezone data, and without a timezone specification in the time to be formatted, there are a few periods where you will get an inconsistent result - e.g. the repeated time following the clocks going back. This is why it is always recommended to record all timestamps in `UTC` - i.e. **never** apply a timezone to the recorded timestamp, record it in GMT, and then back-and-forth with that value as a display variable, which you have total control over.

Linux/BSD have some additional fields that can be used to determine the timezone, and the offset from UTC - e.g. on linux it's the `__tm_gmtoff` field, and in BSD(/Mac OS X) it's called `tm_gmtoff`.

There is an additional field labelling the timezone, which is `__tm_zone` on linux and `tm_zone` in BSD(/Mac OS X), but that field is only populated when you get localtime.

I altered your example slightly, and got the following output:

```
Time entered = 2013-04-05 15:00
I am here.
Error. Check string for formatting of new date.
Details of the time structure:
Years since 1900 = 113
Months since January = 3
Day of the month = 5
Hour = 15 Minute = 0 second = 0
gmtoff = 0
Time since epoch = 1365174000
Reconverting to the time structure:
Details of the time structure:
Years since 1900 = 113
Months since January = 3
Day of the month = 5
Hour = 16 Minute = 0 second = 0
gmtoff = 3600
Zone = IST
Time in date + time = 2013-04-05 15:00 and since epoch = 1365174000
```

If you're using this structure in Windows, you're going to have to use another mechanism, though, as it doesn't have these two extra fields.

Comment: I am on cygwin. I do not have `tm_gmtoff` or `tm_zone`. What are my options? Re-convert from epoch time into date time and if there is a difference of an hour between original and re-converted time, add 3600 seconds to the time since epoch?

Comment: your suggestion of dealing with only UTC is good, but I have no control over the timestamp generation. I have to work with the data. I have been told that the timestamps are recorded in CST.

Comment: @Sriram As I mentioned at the end of the answer Windows doesn't support these fields. I presume you mean that the time is in CST/CDT, rather than strictly CST. The cygwin implementation of strptime is limited. I would recommend using boost for this - it will allow far more sensible date/time handling.

Comment: If you want to roll your own and do (sec/year) * (# of years) you need to take the whole complicated mess of leap years into account too.  If the year is divisible by 4 it's a leap year but that's not exact enough, there are periodic adjustments to that, both scheduled ones and more random ones.  I'm looking at several years of temperature data recorded with time_ts and facing a similar problem.

Comment: It's in the Windows registry somewhere, there's a range of dates that are DST and ones that aren't.  It changed somewhere in 2000 - 2008 and on every Windows machine you had to double ciick on a .reg file to load the change.  That's how I know it' s there.

Comment: Date and time handling is *awful* on c++ without a library. Using built in support, while helpful, is only postponing the pain you’re going to encounter later down the line.